# Unable to send messages to who are not online using node.js on my localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io

I have node up and running with socket.io. I am able to send messages to people who are online on my server(who have their socket connection open). But when i try to send it multiple people  with atleast one offline it doesn't go through. if all are online it goes through.

Any help on how to fix this?

```
client.on('message_from_client',function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i].message_to!=''){
            client.emit("update_message_from_server", data[i]);
            if(data[i].message_to != client.username){
                var message_to = data[i].message_to;
                var array =data[i];
                redisClient.SISMEMBER('online',message_to,function(err,reply){
                    if(reply!=0){
                        redisClient.get(message_to,function(err,reply2){
                            if(reply2!=null){
                                io.sockets.sockets[reply2].emit("update_message_from_server",array );
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.log("Offline");
                    }
                });
            }
        }else{
                client.emit("update_message_from_server", data[i]);
        }   
    }
});
```

data is a JSON object. If i have any data[i].message_to as offline i am only able to send this to client but no other sockets. If i have all entries online i am able to send it to both client and other sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out other way to do this

```
client.on('message_from_client',function(data){
        alldata = data.data;
        console.log(alldata);
        alldata = JSON.parse(alldata);
        alldata.forEach(function(data){
            if(data.message_to!=''){
                client.emit("update_message_from_server", data);
                if(data.message_to != client.username){
                    redisClient.SISMEMBER('online',data.message_to,function(err,reply){
                        if(reply!=0){
                            redisClient.get(data.message_to,function(err,reply2){
                                if(reply2!=null){
                                    io.sockets.sockets[reply2].emit("update_message_from_server",data );
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            console.log("Offline");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }else{
                    client.emit("update_message_from_server", data);
            }   
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you explain the answer a little?